# Hide items when selecting options in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have this `select` element:

```html
<select class="form-control" name="inputContracts" id="inputContracts" required>
    <option value="0">@lang('general.example.select')</option>
    <option value="1">@lang('general.example.value1')</option>
    <option value="2">@lang('general.example.value2')</option>
</select>
```

I want to hide some inputs when selecting an option, how can I do it?

I think you can do it with JavaScript, but I don't know how, can you give me an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the selected value in javascript as follows:

```
var e = document.getElementById("inputContracts");
var value = e.value;
```

Once the value is obtained, you can hide the required element based on if conditon. For example if you want to hide some **input** whose id is **inputCont1** when the value selected is "1", you can do as follows:

```
if(value == "1") {
  document.getElementById("inputCont1").style.display = 'none';
}
```